# Designer not opening - variable is either undeclared or was never assigned

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am unable to open WinForms designer for a user control. On opening the designer getting error that variable is either undeclared or was never assigned. Though the variable (object of a drop down) is already present in designer file itself and project is compiling fine. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Open your <form>.designer.cs class line 920, and see if you can find anything... generally this issue arises when the designer is not in sync with the code

Comment: @Yogi what could not be in sync ?

Answer (score 0):

Click in "Go to Code", you will find error page there, correct it according to your need

Comment: it just takes you to the designer file where variable is being used. Like I said the code is compiling fine. Just that the designer doesn't open.

Comment: Well I have tried everything, reopen, clean, rebuild. Nothing worked.

Comment: what is there on line 920 on designer page?

Comment: pnl.Controls.Add(ddlEditReportGroup)

Comment: For me it worked to switch back to Any CPU instead of 64 bit, then rebuild close the designer and open